# Not displaying array count

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have number of checkboxes on my page and I want to get those checkbox values in my database.

```
$('#assign_data').on("click",function()
    {
        var mandate_array = [];
        var i= 0;

        $('.assign_mandate:checked').each(function(){
             mandate_array[i++] = $(this).val();
        });


        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",   
                url: BASE_URL+"mandate/assign_mandate.php", 
                data: "mandate_array="+mandate_array+"&role_id="+$('#role').val()+"&user_id="+$('#user').val(), 
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    console.log(msg)

                }
            })

    });
```

assign_mandate.php :

```
<?php

  $mandate = explode(',',$_POST['mandate_array']);

  // print_r($mandate);  //it shows the data in array

  count($mandate);exit;  // it does not show the count in console
?>
```

When I print the array it show me the array data in console but when I try to echo the count of array it shows blank. Why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `array_count_values($mandate)`

Comment: @Jenz since $_POST['mandate_array'] get value like 2,3,4 and i want to explode this variable

Comment: @MilindAnantwar tried but same blank result

Comment: Add `echo` before your count.

Comment: echo count($mandate);exit;

Comment: Gah! Why do people keep manually creating strings for the `$.ajax` `data` param?

Comment: @Rikesh really thanks , im such a idiot how i can forget to echo the value. thanks it worked. If you add this as an answer i would accept that answer

Comment: @RickSmarty - Glad to help you. Already posted as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22905521/696364) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to echo the variable count value.

```
    <?php

  $mandate = explode(',',$_POST['mandate_array']);

  // print_r($mandate);  //it shows the data in array

  echo count($mandate);exit;  // it does not show the count in console
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` in front of the `count()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

You would typically convert the array to a JSON string with JSON.stringify, then make an AJAX request to the server, receive the string parameter and json_decode it to get back an array in the PHP side.

```
$('#assign_data').on("click",function()
    {
        var mandate_array = [];
        var i= 0;

        $('.assign_mandate:checked').each(function(){
             mandate_array[i++] = $(this).val();
        });


        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",   
                url: BASE_URL+"mandate/assign_mandate.php", 
                data: "mandate_array="+JSON.stringify(mandate_array)+"&role_id="+$('#role').val()+"&user_id="+$('#user').val(), 
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    console.log(msg)

                }
            })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`mandate_array` is `Array` so you wont posted array data in query string, you should use `JSON.stringfy()` function to convert array/JSON object into string.

```
   $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",   
            url: BASE_URL+"mandate/assign_mandate.php", 
            data: "mandate_array="+JSON.stringfy(mandate_array)+"&role_id="+$('#role').val()+"&user_id="+$('#user').val(), 
            success: function(msg)
            {
                console.log(msg)

            }
        })
```

In PHP code

`var_dump(json_decode($_POST['mandate_array']));`